# Make possible to update the answers to a post by anyone (for current research answers which are frequently moving)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked this question [Review paper on depth, qubits and $T$ gates number on Clifford+T decomposition for various "typical" algorithms](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21518/review-paper-on-depth-qubits-and-t-gates-number-on-cliffordt-decomposition-f)

I feel like the answer to this kind of question can frequently be updated as many papers are produced in this topic.

I wondered if there is an option on stackexchange that could make such questions/answer more in a spirit of something that has to be frequently updated (not necessarily by the person that provided the answer, but by anyone).

Comment: you mean like [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/276202) posts?

Comment: @glS I guess. I didn't know it existed. So I should probably ask the author of the post then to switch it to wiki.

Comment: I don't know that asking someone to make their post CW is appropriate. The main differences between a CW post and a normal one are that with a CW post you don't get rep, there is less emphasis on who the "owner" of the post is, so people are more encouraged to edit it and add things, and the rep threshold to edit the post is lower. It's fine if you want to make a CW post, but I wouldn't assume that someone else wants to make their own post CW without good enough reason

Comment: @glS yeah you are right. It can be annoying for the author to not be recognized anymore. I will probably not ask it then ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting here to not leave the question unanswered: this seems to be exactly what Community Wiki (CW) posts are for. See [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/276202).

Note that you cannot convert questions into CW *after* asking them. Such conversion can only be enacted by a moderator (and would obviously only happen in specific circumstances in which such a change would be deemed as useful/necessary). Personally, I think situations in which this is warranted are quite rare (as in, I cannot think of any that occurred in this site).

Answers can be converted into CW by the owner or moderators. This might be useful if you want to stress that the answer should be thought of as "collectively owned", or as a work in progress that others can contribute to and improve. But then again, I think there is no real need for this in most circumstances. It might make sense for the situation which you are thinking about: have an answer which is based on the state of the art in some field, which can be more easily updated when new things happen in the future, but I don't think it would be particularly appropriate to ask other people to convert their answer into CW. After all, doing so you forgo reputation from future upvotes, which might not be fair given the work one put into writing the answer.